# SCCM 2016 in azure

Tags: azure, sccm

is it recommended or rather is it possible to have a whole system centre configuration manager infrastructure, in azure to manage on premises clients and servers.

The reason I am asking is there seems to be not much information or design example of actually implementing this.

Answer (score 2):

SCCM Current Branch is fully supported in Azure IaaS. There is no limitation with this approach. You can have primary servers and other site system servers in Azure.

Also you can have PXE or some other roles in On Prem Data Center.

SCCM is going to remove the dependency on WDS service for a PXE role. This option is already available in SCCM 1802 preview version.

The following documentation have loads of answers

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/core/understand/configuration-manager-on-azure

Comment: Please note if you want to promote your own product/blog you **must disclose your affiliation in the answer**, otherwise, your answer may be flagged as spam. If you are not affiliated with the site, I recommend you say so to prevent this. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://superuser.com/help/promotion)

Comment: Still missing a statement about your affiliation to the site, anoopcnair one.

Comment: I'm not affiliated to the site

Comment: Are you sure? Your profile says `Microsoft MVP on EMS. Owner of https://www.anoopcnair.com/`

Comment: You may want to look up *affiliate* in a dictionary.

Comment: But I removed my blog site reference from the answer. So I don't have any affiliation with Microsoft and their site ;)

Comment: The last paragraph seems to be missing a link. What's going to be there?

Comment: Done removed as suggested. Is it ok now?

Comment: @AnoopCNair Yes. It is good now.

Comment: Thank you A J - Can you please help to delete the duplicate answer below?

Comment: Also I can't post answers now :( Can you help please

Comment: @AnoopCNair I don't have privileges to help deleting the duplicate answer, but it seems it's already gone. And you will be able to post more answers in a couple of days. So, don't worry about it. We are strict about spamming, therefore we asked you to describe your affiliation with the site `anoopcnair.com`. Since you declined it, we had to downvote and flag it for removal. However, we have now retracted the flags and downvotes, so the answer ban must be lifted in a couple of days. I sincerely apologize for the problems. And Welcome to Stack Exchange! We hope you will enjoy your stay. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you much for helping me here. It's ok now. I can post answers now. I understand your concerns about spamming. I'm also against it. I'm the founder of AnoopCNair.com. But my decline was about the technet and Microsoft documentation. Thank you again. Hope I can add some value to the IT community here as well

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no SCCM 2016, a new SCCM current branch will be released with the Windows Server 2016 or System Center 2016 Suite I guess.

As you said, there are no much public document for this topic, I would like to share with you something.

Actually usually we can consider to put the CAS to the Azure, but not the all SCCM core infrastructure. But technically you can do that

You can already install the SCCM Current Branch 1060 on the Azure, including Primary Site Server, Database, WSUS, Reporting, App Cat, AI etc.
To manage the on premises devices, you need to setup a DP and MP on your premises site.

You need to setup the Site to site VPN between your Azure network and on premises site..

I understand that you only want to manage On premises device, but just want to share with you, some feature needs broadcast won't work for the VMs in Azure, such as PXE, WDS....

Azure does not support broadcast (cf. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-faq/).

“WDS cannot be run on a virtual machine in Windows Azure.”
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831764(v=ws.11).aspx